# Notating a note sustained over clef change

Tags: notation, engraving, clefs

I found this very interesting notation in [Wiklund's first piano concerto](https://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No.1%2C_Op.10_(Wiklund%2C_Adolf)), final bars of movement 1 (the transcription for two pianos):

[image: extract from Wiklund's piano concerto]

See the final left-hand bars: the low E is sustained over a clef change, then into the next bar where the two clefs are stacked atop each other, both applying to one note.

I have never seen that notation before and I doubt that many music notation programs would support it. So that sparked my curiosity; how would a modern musician notate the same passage? Is the only alternative to move the high B to the right-hand stave?

Comment: Concerning whether music notation programs could produce this output:  I suspect you could induce Lilypond to produce that output if you really wanted to.  But I'm not experienced enough with it to be able to produce a working example quickly.

Comment: Any notation program could easily produce it, as long as it had non-functional symbols available of treble and bass clef.   Playback would need to be cheated though.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Definitely true, I meant that I doubt any software supports it natively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 alternatives to that notation that I can notate with Musescore are these:

- Cross-staff the lower staff's uppermost B so the slurred beam in the lower staff of the 3rd last measure connects a chord in the lower staff with a note in the upper staff
- Use 3 staves instead of 2 (heck, this also looks appropriate for the 4th last measure)
- Notate the lower staff's uppermost B with 4 ledger lines in the bass clef instead of using the treble clef

I don't have the greatest clue which of these is the best, but given that I had to count out the ledger lines in order to determine what the bottommost notes are (turns out they're E's), I personally would *not* want to read my last option.

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, this can be a useful and clear way to notate something which would otherwise look messy.  I don't think it's a particularly 'old' way.

Any notation program that supports clef symbols as simple, non-functioning graphic objects could notate this.   Playback would be another matter!  (Though easily enough achieved by muting the displayed notes and adding them in an additional, hidden voice).

Here's a practical alternative.  I suspect I prefer it as notation.   But it's not fun getting the ties to go where you want them. in Sibelius at any rate! (You'll note that I copped out of the challenge.  Give it a try in YOUR notation program.)

[image]